# Is there any problem in my FFMPEG encoder client code?

Tags: c++, sockets, ffmpeg

I am trying to write code have function of capture video stream, encode as hevc265 and send to server as UDP:

```
// There can some unnecessary library imports, rule 1: If it is ok, don't touch it!

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/packet.h>
#include <libavcodec/codec_id.h>
#include <libavutil/error.h>
#include <libavutil/error.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
}

#define PORT 9999
#define IP_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int width = 1080;
    const int height = 720;
    const int fps = 18; 
    const auto resulation = "1080x720";
    const auto device = "/dev/video0";
    const auto format = "v4l2";
    const AVCodecID codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H265;

    avdevice_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = nullptr;

    AVDictionary *format_opts = nullptr;
    av_dict_set(&format_opts, "framerate", "18", 0);;
    av_dict_set(&format_opts, "video_size", resulation, 0);
    
    const AVInputFormat *inputFormat = av_find_input_format(format);
    if (!inputFormat)
    {
        cerr << "Unknown input format: " << format << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Input format: "<< format << endl;

    const AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!codec) {
        cerr << "Codec can't find "<< codec_id << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Found codec: "<< codec_id << endl;

    AVCodecContext *avctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!avctx) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not create encoder!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Create encoder. " << endl;


    avctx->bit_rate = 1000000;
    avctx->width = width; 
    avctx->height = height; 
    avctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P; 
    avctx->time_base = (AVRational){1, fps};
    avctx->framerate = (AVRational){fps, 1};
    avctx->gop_size = fps*2;
    avctx->refs = 3;

    av_opt_set(avctx->priv_data, "preset", "medium", 0);
    av_opt_set(avctx->priv_data, "crf", "18", 0);
    av_opt_set(avctx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);

    if (avcodec_open2(avctx, codec, nullptr) < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Couldn't open codec" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Open codec succesfully." << endl;

    int open_input = avformat_open_input(&formatContext, device,
                                            const_cast<AVInputFormat *>(inputFormat), &format_opts);
    if (open_input != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Device cant open " << device << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Device active: " << device <<endl;

    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if(!frame){
        cerr << "Error: frame" << endl;
        return 1;
    }cout << "Frame has been created." << endl;

    frame->width = avctx->width;
    frame->height = avctx->height;
    frame->format = avctx->pix_fmt;

    if(av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0) != 0){
        cerr << "Error: video frame " << endl;
        return 1;
    }cout << "Video frame has been created." << endl;

    if(av_frame_make_writable(frame) != 0){
        cerr << "Error: frame is not writable" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    AVPacket *packet= av_packet_alloc();
    if (!packet) {
        cerr << "error: has not been created packet" << endl;
    }

    av_dump_format(formatContext, 0, device, 0);
    av_dict_free(&format_opts);
    
    int socket_client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (socket_client == -1) {
        cerr << "Error: socket!" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Socket has been created" << endl;

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr = {0};
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_ADDRESS);

    while (true) {
        if (av_read_frame(formatContext, packet) != 0) {
            cerr << "Error" << endl;
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        }

        frame->data[7] = packet->data; 
        frame->linesize[7] = packet->size;

        if (avcodec_send_frame(avctx, frame) != 0){
            cerr << "Error: Frame sending is missing ---> "<< &av_strerror << endl;
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        }

        if (avcodec_receive_packet(avctx, packet) != 0){
            cerr << "Error: Packet giving is missing! ---> " << &av_strerror << endl;
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        }

        ssize_t snd = sendto(socket_client, packet->data, packet->size,
                            MSG_CONFIRM, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,
                            sizeof(serverAddr));

        if(snd == -1){
            cerr << "Error: Data sending failed !" << endl;
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        }else {
            cout << "Data sending succesfully" << endl;
        }

        av_packet_unref(packet);
        av_frame_unref(frame);
    }

    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&packet);
    close(socket_client);
    avformat_free_context(formatContext);
    avformat_close_input(&formatContext);
    avformat_network_deinit();

    return 0;
}
```

There is such an output, I do not understand the reason yet:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x643732e80b40] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 1080x720 to 1280x720
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x643732e80b40] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 1280x720 to 640x480
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x643732e80b40] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/18 to 1/30
```

Is there any problem in my encoder client code?

In addition, i can't send datas to server.